# Python: How remove punctuation in text corpus, but not remove it in special words (e.g. c++, c#, .net, etc)

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I have a big pandas dataset with job descriptions. I want to tokenize it, but before this I should remove stopwords and punctuation. I have no problems with stopwords.

If I will use regex for removing punctuation, I can lose very important words that describe jobs (e.g. c++ developer, c#, .net, etc.).

List of such important words is very big, because it consists not only programming languages names but also companies names.

For exmaple, I want the next way of removing punctuation:

Before:

> Hi! We are looking for smart, young and hard-working c++ developer. Our perfect candidate should know: - c++, c#, .NET in expert level;

After:

> Hi We are looking for smart young and hard-working c++ developer Our perfect candidate should know  c++ c# .NET in expert level

Can you advise me advance tockenizers or methods for removing punctuation?

Comment: For the punctuation you can try `import re` and then `after = re.sub('[!,\.:-;]', '', before)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not work for such words as: .NET, ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe make a list of the special words and after removing punctuation replace with proper names.

Comment: @RobJan, Yeah, I have thought about it. However, my list of such words is too big. So, maybe some smart tockenizer can be useful, that understand, where dot is punctuation and where it is part of the word. Unfortunately, I do not know such tockenizers(

Comment: Regexes have no intelligence. How could you possibly distinguish between `Let's Go!` and `We need a Go! programmer`? I think you'll always have false positives

Comment: @Julio, I agree with you. So, maybe some tockenizers or another nlp tools exist that can help me with my problem.

Comment: Agree with @Julio you may wanna create a white list, particularly for programming languages, it must not be so hard to find their list online, that would be less time consuming, for the remaining cases you may use the regexes and nlp tools.

Comment: At first I thought about using this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages. That may be an starting point. However, besides programming languages you can also have "technologies", "framworks", ... so it can be worse than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern:

```
[!,.:;-](?= |$)
```

To match any characters `!`,`,`,`.`,`:`,`;` and `-` that are followed by whitespace or end of string.

---

In Python:

```
import re
text = "Hi! We are looking for smart, young and hard-working c++ developer. Our perfect candidate should know: - c++, c#, .NET in expert level;"
print (re.sub(r'[!,.:;-](?= |$)',r'',text))
```

Prints:

```
Hi We are looking for smart young and hard-working c++ developer Our perfect candidate should know  c++ c# .NET in expert level
```

Comment: I am answering the OP. He wants to remove all punctuation marks. `!` is a punctuation mark.

Comment: He said he didn't want to `lose very important words that describe jobs (e.g. c++ developer, c#, .net, etc.).`

Comment: As far as I know, you can use `Go` when referring to the Go language. If the OP wants to add a whitelist to his OP, I will be happy to modify my answer. In the meanwhile, you can remove your downvote since it answers the question.

Comment: The fullstop preceding `net` for instance would not be modified because not followed by whitespace.

Comment: There are `Go` and `Go!`, those are 2 different languages. In the end it was just an example, But using regexes for this will always have false positives. Also, from the OP you can also understand that (at least) he wants to remove `#` and `+`

Comment: `you can also understand that (at least) he wants to remove # and +` No you can't. `#` and `+` are not punctuation marks, at least in English. Also you should stop making assumptions and wait for the OP to clarify himself.

Comment: He said `I can lose very important words... (e.g. c++ developer, c#` You cannot loose `#` or `++` if you don't intend to remove them. Also, looking at the other answer, I am not the only one thinking the same. But ok, let's wat for OP to clarify.

Comment: Again, those are not punctuation characters in English.

Comment: @Julio, I agree with @UnbearableLightness - `!` is punctuation character in English. `Go!` is not such popular programming language (e.g. `Go!` is absent in my dataset from job website).

Comment: It doesn't work with `The programmer should know C--` You will always find false positives.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, Yes, of course! I remember about it. I want to make some test in my dataset. (it will take 5 minute) If it will work I certainly accept your answer. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Julio, `C--` is in the same situation as `Go!`. It is very rare. In fact the UnbearableLightness answer solves my specific problem. Despite this, thank you very much for testing the answers of other users. This helps to critically look to user's answers and to my question.

Comment: @Julio Do you mind removing the downvote since the solution worked for OP?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score -1):

My solution

```
def clean(s: str, keep=None, remove=None):
    """ delete punctuation from "s" except special words """
    if keep is None:
        keep = []

    if remove is None:
        remove = []

    protected = [False for _ in s]  # True if you keep

    # compute protected chars
    for w in keep:  # for every special word
        for i in range(len(s)-len(w)):
            same = True
            for j in range(len(w)):
                if w[j] != s[i + j]:
                    same = False
            if same:
                for j in range(len(w)):
                    protected[i + j] = True

    # delete unwanted chars
    out = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if protected[i]:
            out += s[i]
        else:
            if s[i] not in remove:
                out += s[i]

    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test = "Hi! We are looking for smart, young and hard-working c++ developer. Our perfect candidate should know:" \
           " - c++, c# in expert level;"

    Remove = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '+', '-', '!', '?', '#']
    Keep = ['c++', 'c#']

    print(clean(test, keep=Keep, remove=Remove))
```